# UIBarButtonItem makes my iPhone app crash

Tags: ios, memory, crash, uibarbuttonitem, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to do the most I can programmatically.

I've to add an UIBarButtonItem to a NavigationController's nav bar created in the App Delegate.

```
WPViewController *mainVC = [[WPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WPViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];        
[navCon pushViewController:mainVC animated:NO];
[self.window addSubview:navCon.view];
```

Then in the implementation file of the here declared `WPViewController` I create and add the barbuttonitem as a navigation item of the VC:

```
UIBarButtonItem *rBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(test)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rBarButtonItem;
```

There is a method called test declared before of this that simply log "test", but when I click on the button the app crashes.

Please help me, this bug is driving me crazy.

Notes:

- I'm using ARC in my project
- Never had a similar bug before

Comment: I just got an exc_bad_access message

Comment: set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES and debug.

Comment: Here is the output: -[WPViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6b09c40

Comment: Looks like you better turn off that ARC :P

Comment: Try to call initWithRootViewController instead of init when you istantiate UINavigationController. `UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];`. In what place are triyng to create the button item? The viewDidLoad is the right place.

Comment: If it is possible, you colud provide more info about your code. If you call the first snippet of code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` delagate, I suggest to create an instance variable for your navigation controller like this `@property (nonatomic, reatin) UINavigationController* mainNav;` In this manner you are able to have full control on your navigation for memory management.

Comment: In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` you coul write like this: `UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC]; self.mainNav = navCon;`. Then release your mainVC. Hope it helps. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" Message sent to deallocated instance" in ARC means the compiler has marked, and released, your item before your message could be sent.

Set NSZombieEnabled, MallocStackLogging, and guard malloc in the debugger. Then, when your App crashes, type this in the console:

(gdb) info malloc-history //address of crashing object i.e. 0x543216//

Comment: `[object release]` is invalid with ARC enabled. Even if you try to use `@selector(release)` it throws a build time error.

Comment: So then he needs to turn off ARC because the compiler thinks he's done with that object.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when using `addSubview` but creating a property with `(nonatomic, strong)` strong solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

The Button tries to pass itself as an argument to the test method. I guess your signature of that method doesn't include an argument, because there's no colon in your selector (it should be `@selector(test:)`). And the method implementation should look like:

```
- (void) test:(id)sender
```

Comment: I've already tried what you're saying and the problem is still there.

Comment: If you read the output in the comments section of the OP, you will notice that it wasn't an invalid selector, it was a deallocated instance.

Comment: right, the comment with the output wasn't there when I posted this answer. Sorry